# SQLAlchemy ORM: Re-using VALUES parameter in INSERT statement with inlined SELECT

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to do an insertion using the SQLAlchemy ORM, looking up a default value with an inline select statement that depends on one of the other values. For example:

```
INSERT INTO foo (template_id, bar) 
     VALUES (%(template_id)s, 
             (SELECT template.bar_default 
                FROM template 
               WHERE template.id = %(template_id)s))
RETURNING foo.id
```

[The `default` param in SQLAlchemy allows SQL expressions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/defaults.html#sql-expressions) such as `select()`, so I was thinking of setting it to: `select([Template.bar_default]).where(Template.id == bindparam('template_id')`, like so:

```
class Template(sa.Model):
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    bar_default = sa.Column(sa.String(20))


class Foo(sa.Model):
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    template_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey(Template.id))
    bar = sa.Column(sa.String(20),
                          default=select([Template.bar_default])
                                  .where(Template.id == bindparam('template_id'))))
```

However, this approach does not work. It fails with the following exception:

> sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: bindparam() name 'template_id' is
>   reserved for automatic usage in the VALUES or SET clause of this
>   insert/update statement.   Please use a name other than column name
>   when using bindparam() with insert() or update() (for example,
>   'b_template_id').

`bindparam()` refuses to allow re-using the name from VALUES, even though this is exactly what I need here. Is there a way to avoid the exception?

---

My workaround for now as suggested by @lrnzcig:

```
def before_insert_listener(mapper, connection, target):
    if target.template_id and not target.bar:
            target.bar = select([Template.bar_default])\
                                      .where(Template.id == target.template_id)

event.listen(Foo, 'before_insert', before_insert_listener)
```

Comment: No idea why this is happening, honestly. Maybe the combination of `default` value and `bindparam` is not foreseen? Have you tried to do it with a normal `insert-select` statement? i.e. with the `select` as a value of your `insert`. It should work with no problem with an `insert-select`.

Comment: @lrnzcig it is not ideal since the select statement needs to be built manually  before insert --- but it works and I will go with it for now, so thanks!

Comment: Why manually? I think you should be able to do it with a subquery. Anyway, glad it helped.

Comment: @lrnzig I meant I have to build the subquery manually if I cannot bind to the parameters of the parent.

Comment: Still encountering this issue 8 years later, and the docs still don't address it. I feel like I'm missing something.